# how to determine the headphones is inserted in Windows phone Device?

Tags: windows-phone-7

well.
about my Windows phone Application .
how to determine the headphones is inserted ?

i did't found any  API in Windows phone SDK.

Comment: Any updates on this for Windows Phone 8?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure that you can currently access this information as the API does not appear to expose this device information.

Hopefully more hardware information will be available in the Windows Phone 8 'Apollo' release. There's already been confirmation that you can access lower level unmanaged API calls (think pInvoke) in the next release.

Comment: Thanks For your Reply . i was try like this https://gist.github.com/2659600 . but it was does't work. and i did't found other ways。 did u have any suggestion?

Comment: Just to confirm, there's no public API for this in Windows Phone 7.0, 7.1 or 7.1.1

Answer (score 2):

There is no API that does this, but off the top of my head there may be a 'hacky' workaround you might want to test. I haven't tried it, but the headphones also act as an antennae for the radio. Therefore, you could try measuring the [FMRadio.SignalStrength](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.devices.radio.fmradio.signalstrength%28VS.92%29.aspx) property and seeing if it's below a certain threshold (you'd have to test with and without headphones to determine what that threshold it). If there's very low reception, then it may be possible that the headphones are not connected. It won't be perfect, but might work for you.

Comment: nice idea but it would be difficult to determine what the initial state was without instructing the user to remove the headphones first. I like the suggestion though :-) +1

Comment: Thanks, it was very long shot :D Would definitely need user calibration to be worthwhile and, even then, it would be quite inaccurate.

Comment: to ALL this way may be does't work only then use have been open hub.